# gradle installDist: How do I prepend the group id to dependency jar name (clashing due to different group id but same artifact id and version)?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

#### The problem in Gradle

I have this `build.gradle` in a directory named `proj`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.davfx:util:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.johnnei:util:1.0.0'
}
```

I then run `gradle installDist` and find that the directory `build/install/proj/lib` contains only one `util-1.0.0.jar`. I am expecting two `util-1.0.0.jar` files, but I think this is impossible due to the way file systems work.

The question is: **How do I prefix the jar names with the group id?** Does Gradle have something like Maven's [prependGroupId](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#prependGroupId)?

#### The same problem in Maven

To reproduce the problem, copy the following fragment to `pom.xml`, and run `mvn dependencies:copy-dependencies` in the same directory. Observe that the `target/dependency` directory contains only one file `util-1.0.0.jar`. However, unlike Gradle, Maven can solve this by [prependGroupId](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#prependGroupId). (Credit goes to Tunaki in the comment section.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.spacetimecat</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.davfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.johnnei</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

#### Old (more general) problem description

Let there be two projects with these coordinates:

- `G:A:1.2.3`,
- `H:A:1.2.3`,

that is, they have different group id but the same artifact id and version.

Suppose that I create a project `P` that depends on both of those. I am getting only one `web-1.7.0.jar` file when I assemble a distribution package (a package containing my project jar and all its transitive dependencies). The problem is: one of the jar files in the dependencies get overwritten because they have the same file name, because Gradle/Maven by default names the jars like `artifactId-version-classifier.jar`, although they have different groups.

Comment: `dependency:get` only resolve a single artifact, so there cannot be conflict. I'm not sure what is the problem?

Comment: I updated the question. Let me know if there's still something unclear. Thanks.

Comment: But how is that possible, considering `dependency:get` resolve only _a single_ artifact, and it stores it into your local repository where there cannot be conflicts?

Comment: I see. I think I mean 'assemble' (prepare a distribution), not 'dependency:get'

Comment: Hi @Tunaki, I added instructions to reproduce the problem with Maven, so this problem affects both Gradle and Maven. Do you mind if we add the 'maven' tag back? Thanks.

Comment: Gradle and Maven are two completely different tools, please focus on one. I wouldn't know how to solve this in Gradle. In Maven, since you now use `copy-dependencies`, there are multiple solutions, like [`prependGroupId`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#prependGroupId).

Answer (score 4):

It's messy but you could declare your dependencies against a `tempCompile` configuration and then add a `renamejars` task to the `DAG` which renames the jars into a `$buildDir/renamedJars` directory. The `compile` configuration could then include jars from `$buildDir/renamedJars` directory.

**Important** - This solution will lose the group/artifact/version for all dependencies meaning that downstream projects will not be able to perform dependency resolution.

```
configurations {
    tempCompile
}
dependencies {
    tempCompile 'com.davfx:util:1.0.0'
    tempCompile 'org.johnnei:util:1.0.0'
    compile fileTree("$buildDir/renamedJars")
}
task renameJars {
    inputs.files configurations.tempCompile
    outputs.dir "$buildDir/renamedJars"
    doLast {
        mkdir "$buildDir/renamedJars"
        ResolvedConfiguration rc = configurations.tempCompile.resolvedConfiguration
        Set<ResolvedArtifact> artifacts = rc.resolvedArtifacts
        artifacts.each { ra ->
            ModuleVersionIdentifier mvi = ra.moduleVersion.id
            copy {
                from ra.file
                into "$buildDir/renamedJars"
                rename { old ->
                    return "${mvi.group}-${mvi.name}-${ra.classifier}-${mvi.version}.${ra.extension}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
compileJava.dependsOn renameJars
```

See

- [Configuration.getResolvedConfiguration()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html#getResolvedConfiguration%28%29)
- [ResolvedConfiguration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ResolvedConfiguration.html)
- [ResolvedArtifact](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ResolvedArtifact.html)
- [ModuleVersionIdentifier](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleVersionIdentifier.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised I haven't heard of this issue before, I'm guessing the War plugin suffers from the same problem. Interesting to see that maven suffers from the same problem.

The [java library distribution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/javaLibraryDistribution_plugin.html) plugin adds a `distZip` task which is of type [Zip](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Zip.html) which has a [rename](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html#rename(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method so you can likely do this

```
def count = 1
distZip {
    rename 'util.*\\.jar', "util${count++}.jar"
}
```

Comment: Hi Lance, thanks for spending time answering the question. I'm sorry I didn't state the question clearly; I've edited it. Do you know how I can prepend the dependency's group id to the jar name? I think the `rename` method doesn't have information about the dependency's group id.